# Transforming code from C to Java

Tags: java, c, transform

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ST_PARAMETROV        4          //stevilo vhodnih parametrov
#define VEL_SPOMINA          10000      //velikost spomina +-10000
#define VEL_PROGRAMA         10000      //največja velikost programa
#define DOVOLJENIH_UKAZOV    10000      //največje dovoljeno število ukazov

int main() {

    // \0 označuje konec programa
    char program[VEL_PROGRAMA] = ",.>,<<,->--->+++.<.<.\0";
    int programPointer = 0;

    char parametri[ST_PARAMETROV] = {20,30,40,50};
    int parametriPointer = 0;

    unsigned char spomin[VEL_SPOMINA*2] = {0};
    int spominPointer = VEL_SPOMINA;

    int stOklepajev;
    int stOpravljenihUkazov = 0;


    while(program[programPointer] != 0 && DOVOLJENIH_UKAZOV > stOpravljenihUkazov){
        switch(program[programPointer]){
            case '>':
                spominPointer ++;
            break;

            case '<':
                spominPointer --;
            break;

            case '+':
                spomin[spominPointer] ++;
            break;

            case '-':
                spomin[spominPointer] --;
            break;

            case '.':
                printf("%i\n",spomin[spominPointer]);
            break;

            case ',':
                //če je zmanka parametrov zapiše 0
                if(parametriPointer > ST_PARAMETROV-1)spomin[spominPointer] = 0;
                else spomin[spominPointer] = parametri[parametriPointer++];
            break;

            case '[':
                if(spomin[spominPointer] == 0){
                    stOklepajev = 1;
                    while(stOklepajev != 0){
                        programPointer ++;
                        if(program[programPointer] == ']'){
                            stOklepajev--;
                        }
                        if(program[programPointer] == '['){
                            stOklepajev++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            case ']':
            if(spomin[spominPointer] != 0){
                stOklepajev = 1;
                while(stOklepajev != 0){
                    programPointer--;
                    if(program[programPointer] == '['){
                        stOklepajev--;
                    }
                    if(program[programPointer] == ']'){
                        stOklepajev++;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;


        }
        programPointer ++;
        stOpravljenihUkazov++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hi could anybody help me please, I am having some difficulties transforming this code from C language to Java language, could anybody who can do this without any problems and with an ease. I already tried it to transfrom it into Java, but I fail everytime with many errors.
I would really appreciate if someone could just tranform the code into Java and then I will correct the errors myself.

Code itself is a Brainfuck interpreter. 
Thanks

Comment: You can post your attempt (Java) here, so we can try and correct it. As far as I know, it'd be rather easy to transform.

Comment: Right, doesn´t look too hard to do, but we won´t do your homework if you don´t at least try. And there is a reason why english variable names etc. make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#defines` will probably have to be const char.
Your `case` switches will have to be converted to

```
if
else if
else if
 ...
else
```

After that it should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

The needful transformations are limited to class and object definitions/initialization and `return`:

```
public class Brainfuck
{
    final static int
        ST_PARAMETROV     =     4,  //stevilo vhodnih parametrov
        VEL_SPOMINA       = 10000,  //velikost spomina +-10000
        VEL_PROGRAMA      = 10000,  //najve?ja velikost programa
        DOVOLJENIH_UKAZOV = 10000;  //najve?je dovoljeno ?tevilo ukazov

    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        // \0 ozna?uje konec programa
        char program[] = new char[VEL_PROGRAMA];
        char initialProgram[] = ",.>,<<,->--->+++.<.<.\0".toCharArray();
        System.arraycopy(initialProgram, 0, program, 0, initialProgram.length);
        int programPointer = 0;

        char parametri[] = {20, 30, 40, 50};
        int parametriPointer = 0;

        char spomin[] = new char[VEL_SPOMINA*2];
        int spominPointer = VEL_SPOMINA;

        int stOklepajev;
        int stOpravljenihUkazov = 0;

        while (program[programPointer] != 0
            && DOVOLJENIH_UKAZOV > stOpravljenihUkazov)
        {
            switch (program[programPointer])
            {

                case '>':
                    spominPointer++;
                break;

                case '<':
                    spominPointer--;
                break;

                case '+':
                    spomin[spominPointer]++;
                break;

                case '-':
                    spomin[spominPointer]--;
                break;

                case '.':
                    System.out.println((int)spomin[spominPointer]);
                break;

                case ',':
                    //?e je zmanka parametrov zapi?e 0
                    if (parametriPointer > ST_PARAMETROV-1)
                         spomin[spominPointer] = 0;
                    else spomin[spominPointer] = parametri[parametriPointer++];
                break;

                case '[':
                    if (spomin[spominPointer] == 0)
                    {
                        stOklepajev = 1;
                        while (stOklepajev != 0)
                        {
                            programPointer++;
                            if(program[programPointer] == ']') stOklepajev--;
                            if(program[programPointer] == '[') stOklepajev++;
                        }
                    }
                break;

                case ']':
                    if(spomin[spominPointer] != 0)
                    {
                        stOklepajev = 1;
                        while(stOklepajev != 0)
                        {
                            programPointer--;
                            if(program[programPointer] == '[') stOklepajev--;
                            if(program[programPointer] == ']') stOklepajev++;
                        }
                    }
                break;

            }
            programPointer++;
            stOpravljenihUkazov++;
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```